# Central command logging on Linux

Tags: linux, security, shell, logging

I'm looking for a solution that will log all commands typed in to a central system.  I have looked at the *accton* service, but see that it can only log to the local file system.

Is there a service like Cisco's TACACS+ that can log all commands on a central server for auditing?

Comment: When you say 'only log to the local file system', are you indicating that you want to all commands typed on a group of servers to be accessible from some common file shared from a SAN or other networked device? Are you looking for an enterprise level repository of commands issued? Would you expect it to 'explode' the calls to other programs made by a shell script (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help [lastcomm](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/log-all-commands-executed-by-any-user-possible-740073/page2.html)

there is also script

man script

Answer (score 1):

If you want to audit everything your users *type* at a console, then [`pam_tty_audit(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/pam_tty_audit.8.html) may be exactly what you need. This requires the `auditd` auditing daemon, which most distributions provide (if not installed by default).

The `auditctl.conf(5)` config file might also be able to do what you want; you can configure the audit daemon to log all `execve(2)` calls. [nixcraft](http://nixcraft.com/networking-firewalls-security/15347-suse-auditd-rules-root-account.html) has collected some `auditctl` rules that you might find useful to steal; note he uses both `b32` and `b64` architectures, because `auditd` uses syscall *numbers* behind the scenes, and there is no guarantee that syscall numbers are identical between 32-bit and 64-bit processes on a system.

You can use the `audispd(8)` plugin [`audisp-remote(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/audisp-remote) to log the audit events to a remote machine.